# SugarCRM rest endpoints

Tags: rest, rubygems, sugarcrm

Forgive if this question is silly. I just started reading the SugarCRM developer documentation and got confused on the endpoints for REST. The CE edition has rest.php as the endpoint for REST. So, if I write my app to contact these php endpoints, will this hold good for the on-demand version as well. Please let me know if it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the endpoints are consistent across all editions of Sugar.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoints do not differ based on SugarCRM editions. In addition I would use the url based on the version of the API. That way you are sure that SugarCRM upgrades don't change the API signature.

So on SugarCRM version 6.4, the urls are: ([source](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.4/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.4.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_640.html#9000493))

- SugarCRM v5.5: http://localhost/service/v2/rest.php
- SugarCRM v6.1: http://localhost/service/v3/rest.php
- SugarCRM v6.1: http://localhost/service/v3_1/rest.php
- SugarCRM v6.2: http://localhost/service/v4/rest.php